# How to use multiple tls protocols

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, .net-4.6.1

So I have an application currently using .net4.6.1 but for some reason config file is still saying targetframework = net4.5 -> don't ask why I cannot change it since it's a cms system.

We are using a post to an external api endpoint a figured it can only use tlsv1.2.
to aquire this I placed this code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Works perfectly, but i broke the other webclient tough :(.

So the other webclient can only use tls1.0 or tls1.1 to manage this i have mchanged to this code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Well certainly my tls exception got away but still this post is not received no errors in event viewer either.

Using wireshark the client send hello with tls v1.2 and server responds with tls1.0.

Any idea how I can use httpclient with tls1.2 and webclient with v1.0 or v1.1?

Comment: When communicating in http there is a negotiation between the client and server using the headers.  I can't tell from your posting if the tls1.0 response means an attempt was made to connect using TLS1.0 or just that the server only supports TLS1.0.  The TLS connection is made with TCP layer.  So to see if the TLS competed you would need to look at TCP.  Check if the TCP connection closed.  You should see a [FIN].  Compare working and non working to better understand the protocol.

Comment: Well the first server is only using tlmsv1.2 not lower, while the other server only supports tlsv1.0 andtlsv1.1, but thx that's a start to find out

Comment: @jdweng well nope it does not look like i get client hello  then 3 ack a server hello certificate,hello done then client key exchange, then application data which I assume would be the content i send, back a few ack's and then a tcp dup ack

Comment: So when you get TLSV1.0 you have to try a new request with only TLS1.0.

Comment: I already found it it's exaclty the code i used but it was at the wrong place